# Two textarea side by side with max size that fill place whole covering website like in sublime text editor, with two columns layout?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive-design

Here the example of sublime text view with two columns focus group:

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You can use `flexbox` to achieve it

Answer (score 2):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

textarea {
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <textarea name="" id="" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" id="" rows="10"></textarea>
</section>
```